# set text to end of webview

Tags: android, android-webview

```
    mview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/any.htm");
    summery += "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
    mview.loadData(summery, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

but this code display only last added text not html file?

I want to display both. how it's possible?

Comment: This is an old post, but figured I'd throw in my two cents: the Webview may start to load the URL, but immediately after, you're telling it to set its data ONLY to the "summery" string (replacing the content, rather than adding to it). If you wish to add the string to the bottom of an HTML, your best bet is to inject it into the DOM via JavaScript, perhaps triggered by the onPageFinished method of the WebViewClient.